# how do I change the field delimiter after the nth column

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file with thousand of lines like below

```
32322621661395926569;adverline;www.societe.com_societe;identite;Salarie2;fiche;btp_et_construction;CA4
32322621661395926569;adverline;www.societe.com_societe;identite;Salarie2;fiche;energy;CA4;nunuc_muchemuche
```

The delimiter is done with `;`. I'm trying to change the delimiter after the 4th column. So every semi-colon after `identite` will be changed to a `,`.

I've tried that

```
awk '$4=$4' FS=";" OFS="," filename
```

but it is changing everything to a comma.

if you have any tips, I'm all ears.

Comment: Hi  HuStmpHrrr, how? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can [specify the occurrence](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-8) using `sed`:

```
sed 's/;/,/4g' file
```

Results:

```
32322621661395926569;adverline;www.societe.com_societe;identite,Salarie2,fiche,btp_et_construction,CA4
32322621661395926569;adverline;www.societe.com_societe;identite,Salarie2,fiche,energy,CA4,nunuc_muchemuche
```

Answer (score 1):

this piece of perl code should work.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open FH, $filename; # fill it in
while (<FH>){
    my @elems = split ';', $_;
    push @elems, join ',', splice @elems, 3, @elems - 3;
    print join ';', @elems;
}
```